# Need somewhere to post form responses

Tags: sql, database, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to work out where to put the responses to a GravityForm that I have hosted on WordPress.  GravityForms displays them as entry/detail which is not a good way to see how many of x people there are etc.

I need an excel-esqe grid that can be edited by multiple users, so I was thinking Google docs, but I would rather keep the data on my server.

My end users are not particularly IT literate so the front end needs to be quite user friendly.

Is there any solution that I can host on my server and post data in to?  I was playing with the idea of writing the form responses to a separate WordPress table but I need a very easy way to edit them.

I'd be grateful to hear any feedback or ideas you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Manual data copy

EtherCalc is good. The problem is how to get the data in and out of the spreadsheet,
if a manual export and import will work, then you can use EtherCalc.
EtherCalc is a google docs style spreadsheet, edited by multiple users. 
 You can host it on your own server.

### Pay a developer to automate

As above, but pay a developer to automate the movement of data. Would take a few days of work.

### Google docs form

I saw a google docs forms plugin that does this already. Maybe you saw that already.

### EtherCalc forms feature.

I will add a forms feature to EtherCalc over xmas.